# How to position five copies of a label relative to other label with touch in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, touchesbegan

I have two columns of labels with some text. How can i get 3rd Column of label attached to column1 when i touch on any label of my second column.
Here is code for column1 and Column2 labels

Column1 labels

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{


    _lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect1];
   // lbl.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width+10, 30);
    _lbl.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
    _lbl.tag=i;
    _lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    _lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    _lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    //label.clipsToBounds=YES;
    //label.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lbl];
    _lbl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _lbl.text=@"Text1";
    [_lbl sizeToFit];
```

Column2 for labels

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{


    _lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
   // _lbl2.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width+10, 30);
    _lbl2.center = CGPointMake(x+20, y);
    _lbl2.tag=i+5;
    _lbl2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    _lbl2.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    _lbl2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    //_lbl2.clipsToBounds=YES;
    //_lbl2.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lbl2];
    _lbl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _lbl2.text=@"Text2";
    [_lbl2 sizeToFit];
```

In touches Begin method i call a method `makeThirdColumn`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

      {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
        _xOffset = pt.x - self.center.x;
        _yOffset = pt.y - self.center.y;
        [self makeThirdColumn];
```

I,m not getting 3rd column of labels at required position as in this image only two columns are[image]

I want to get 3rd column concate with  column1 Text1 label.

Comment: Based on your code... First, you create 5 labels with no text, so just plain green rectangles, all on top of each other, so the result is ONE green box. Second, you do the same with 5 red labels, again on top of each other, resulting in ONE red box. Third, you create 5 labels, each time through setting the frame, then changing the origin of the frame, then changing the whole frame, again all on top of each other. Plus... you do not create any references to the labels you are adding, so in "make third row" there is no label1 or label2.

Comment: I would suggest --- Step One: write code that properly creates your first two "rows" of  labels. Then edit your question showing *that* code, plus an image of how it looks and showing where you want the 3rd row of labels to show up.

Comment: oh i see it let me update my code

Comment: @DonMag see now i want my 3rd row should attatched to row1

Comment: ok... maybe language difference, but you are showing *columns* not *rows*. Also, the code you are showing does **not** create that image. Impossible to help you unless you show the actual code you are using.

Comment: If this isn't a classic example of why you should use xibs/storyboards, I don't know what is.

Comment: i,m not using storyboards

Comment: Is this (about) what you want ?  https://imgur.com/a/qWxEb

Comment: @DonMag yes exactly

Comment: and the 3rd column appear when i touch any one label from column2 i hop you got my point?

Comment: Probably the *easy* thing to do: create the 3rd column of labels the same way you create the 1st and 2nd columns, but set `label.hidden = YES;`. Then when a label from column 2 is tapped, loop through the 3rd column labels and set `hidden = NO;`

Comment: but my 3rd column labels size should be same as second columns labels size the size of label is according to string and it may vary....

Comment: i try to set but it pops up on the label which one is tapped..!!

Comment: @DonMag can i update my question again?

Comment: Yes, update your question and try to explain what you want to do. I assume you want something other than "Text1" "Text2" "Text3" -- so give examples. And, explain what should happen when a `ColumnB` label is tapped... Should *all* `ColumnC` labels be shown? Only one? Does the text in `C` change depending on which `B` label is tapped? Difficult to help, if you don't say what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DonMag i have different words on my labelB and make its size with text thats why i want an empty columnC to drag and fit labelB into labelC when i tap on labelB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Moon - I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but hopefully this will help you on your way.

To try and make it a little more clear, I used Columns named A, B and C instead of 1, 2 and 3. This is the result - the Red "Column C" labels will show or hide when you tap the Gray "Column B" labels.

[image]

If this doesn't do what you want (or if you can't figure out how to make this do what you want), you will need to be *much* more clear in describing your goal.

---

```
//  LabelColumnsViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LabelColumnsViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

---

```
//  LabelColumnsViewController.m

#import "LabelColumnsViewController.h"

@interface LabelColumnsViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *gameLayer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *columnA;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *columnB;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *columnC;

@end

@implementation LabelColumnsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add a UIView to hold the Labels
    _gameLayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _gameLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_gameLayer];

    // initialize arrays to hold references to the labels
    _columnA = [NSMutableArray array];
    _columnB = [NSMutableArray array];
    _columnC = [NSMutableArray array];

    // set rows to 5
    int length = 5;

    // top of top row
    CGFloat y1 = 100.0;

    // left of Column A
    CGFloat x1 = 20.0;

    // left of Column B
    CGFloat x2 = 220.0;

    // Vertical spacing for rows of labels
    CGFloat yInc = 40.0;

    // initialize a CGRect
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, 100, 30);

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {

        // Create UILabel for Column A
        UILabel *lblA = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
        lblA.tag = 100+i;
        lblA.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        lblA.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblA.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
        [self.gameLayer addSubview:lblA];
        lblA.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        lblA.text=@"Text1";
        [lblA sizeToFit];


        // "move" the rectangle, so the next label starts at column B
        rect1.origin.x = x2;

        // Create UILabel for Column B
        UILabel *lblB = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
        lblB.tag = 200+i;
        lblB.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblB.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        lblB.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblB.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
        [self.gameLayer addSubview:lblB];
        lblB.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        lblB.text=@"Text2";
        [lblB sizeToFit];

        // add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the label
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
        [lblB addGestureRecognizer:tap];


        // "move" the rectangle, so the next label starts at column C
        // this is the right-edge of the Column A label
        rect1.origin.x = lblA.frame.origin.x + lblA.frame.size.width;

        // Create UILabel for Column C
        UILabel *lblC = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
        lblC.tag = 300+i;
        lblC.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblC.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lblC.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblC.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
        [self.gameLayer addSubview:lblC];
        lblC.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        lblC.text=@"Text3";
        [lblC sizeToFit];

        // Column C is initially Hidden
        lblC.hidden = YES;


        // add the labels to their Arrays so we can access them later
        [_columnA addObject:lblA];
        [_columnB addObject:lblB];
        [_columnC addObject:lblC];


        // reset left of rect to Column A, and increment y (for next row)
        rect1.origin.x = x1;
        rect1.origin.y += yInc;

    }

}

- (void) gotTapped:(id)sender {
    // a label in Column B was tapped, so show Column C labels if they were hidden,
    //      or hide them if they were visible
    for (UILabel *v in _columnC) {
        v.hidden = !v.hidden;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: you are right but it solve my half problem .my problem is how i make the cloumnC labels size same as ColumnB labels . suppose my columnB labels have some rendom strings and its size according to text then how i generate same size of labels in ColumnC when tap on any label in columnB

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a gestureRecogniser and add it to gameLayer view.
2. Implement target method 
   `func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool`
3. You can determine label of second column by setting special tag eg. (For first column i + 1000, second column i+2000 etc)
4. if (gestureRecognizer.view.tag - 2000 >0) then this is second column and you will get corresponding first column label, then you create a new third column label as well.

Any question? Comment.